# Get origin time from a datetime string with offset

Tags: c#, datetime

If I run:

```
// 7:10 am at a location which has a +2 offset from UTC
string timeString = "2011-06-15T07:10:25.894+02:00";
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(timeString);
```

It gives me `time = 6/14/2011 10:10:25 PM`. This is the local time where I am at (Pacific time i.e. UTC -7).

Is there an **elegant** way of getting the local time at the origin i.e. `6/15/2011 07:10:25 AM`?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong: or you use `DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(timeString)` or `DateTime.TryParse(timeString, out time)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) structure seems to be built to specifically handle timezones. It includes most of the functionality of the `DateTime` type.

```
string timeString = "2011-06-15T07:10:25.894+02:00"; 
DateTimeOffset time = DateTimeOffset.Parse(timeString);
```

As [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267.aspx) illustrates, you should `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` whenever you need to unambiguously identify a single point in time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396389.aspx):

```
DateTime localTime = DateTime.Now;

TimeZoneInfo targetTimeZone =
  TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime targetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(localTime, targetTimeZone);
```

Actually, the [`ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396328.aspx) method would be even more succinct:

```
DateTime targetTime =
  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(localTime, "Eastern Standard Time");
```

You can get information for time zones available using [`TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can format the way DateTime is Parse.
For example, if I want the DateTime to be format in french Canadian format :

```
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("fr-CA", true);
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd-MM-yyyy", culture);
```

You can do it the same way for a en-US culture and add the time format to specify the format you want ...

Answer (score 0):

Lock into using TimeZoneInfo - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx to do conversions. FindSystemTimeZoneById  and ConvertTimeFromUtc should be enough. You may need to convert your local DateTime to UTC first with DateTime.ToUniversalTime.